# Adding parameters in ...args

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging

I am making a debug `console.log` wrapper like this:

```
debug = logger('[DEBUG] ' + ...args)
info = logger('[INFO] ' + ...args)
warn = logger('[WARN] ' + ...args)
error = logger('[ERR] ' + ...args)

function logger (...args) {
   console.log(arguments[0] + ' ' + arguments[1])
}

info('This is some info')
debug('This is some debug')
warn('This is some warn')
error('This is some error')
```

But I am getting an error:

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '...'
```

How can I pass a parameter before the ...args? Or any other SIMPLE way I can do what I want to achieve above?

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/keechan/e3wxLjmt/29/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've mixed up how the rest operator works and where it needs to be defined.  Also, you pass `args` but then try to use `arguments`.  Here is a working solution that converts your declarations to functions that accept args, and then use it in `logger`:

```js
const debug = (args) => logger('[DEBUG] ' + args)
const info = (args) => logger('[INFO] ' + args)
const warn = (args) => logger('[WARN] ' + args)
const error = (args) => logger('[ERR] ' + args)

function logger (...args) {
   console.log(args[0] + ' ' + args[1])
}

info('This is some info')
debug('This is some debug')
warn('This is some warn')
error('This is some error')
```

Keep in mind though, in the above you're still not really using the function the way you intended-- we're only passing a single argument (the two strings pre-concatenated).  But you can see that it also works if you pass separate args:

```js
const debug = (msg) => logger('[DEBUG] ', msg)
const info = (msg) => logger('[INFO] ', msg)
const warn = (msg) => logger('[WARN] ', msg)
const error = (msg) => logger('[ERR] ', msg)

function logger (...args) {
   console.log(args[0] + ' ' + args[1])
}

info('This is some info');
debug('This is some debug');
warn('This is some warn');
error('This is some error');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can accept a string parameter in your logger function and return a new function that prepends the string before logging.

```
function logger (str) {
   return function(...args){
       console.log(str, ...args);
   }
}
debug = logger('[DEBUG]')
info = logger('[INFO]')
warn = logger('[WARN]')
error = logger('[ERR]')
```

[Demo!](https://ideone.com/P0K2mh)